# Make a shape and animate it in JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I want to create a L shape with lines (div element). I also want to animate it. The problem is that when I try to rotate it (using transform rotate), the whole line gets rotated. How do I get it done? Can anyone help? Below is the code snippet. How do I make it a L.

```css
.line {
  width: 100px;
  background: #ff0000;
  animation: animate-line 2s;
  height: 2px;
}

@keyframes animate-line {
    0% {
        width: 50px;
    }
  
    100% {
        width: 300px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, I want the same.

Comment: Then i suggest using a canvas

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to do this with SVG ?

Comment: This can be made in css but canvases or SVGs are much more resource-cheap, unless you create the L-shape and set a gradient background, and animate the backround-position.

Comment: It's [`<animateMotion>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animateMotion)

Comment: Thanks for this but I also want the path to be animated like I have in the snippet.

Comment: Though actually an SVG mask in the shape of an L might be more helpful for what you want to do. You could just move a rectangle diagonally and mask through an L.

Comment: Is there any reference to this. I want to get it done quickly.

Comment: Oh, you mean you want StackOverflow to do it for you, eh ? *sigh*… I gave you the link for animateMotion, and here is the [`<mask>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/mask). Need help with the `<rect>` too ?

Comment: No I think I can do it on my own now. Thanks

Comment: (don't worry, I'm sure someone will answer with exactly the right code soon enough — just too tired right now — but you should definitely give it a try on your own, it's kinda relaxing to do simple animations in SVG once you grasp the basics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply without using JS or an SVG image you can animate the elements width and height and use borders

```css
.line {
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  background: transprent;
  border-top: 2px solid red;
  border-right: 2px solid red;
  animation: animate-line 2s linear forwards;
}

@keyframes animate-line {
  0% {
    width: 50px;
    height: 0px;
  }

  50% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 0px;
  }

  100% {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

If that isn't what you wanted please provide an image with an example.

Comment: This solves my problem. But what if I want to make a shape like Z. These borders won't be applicable all the time I guess.